# Consume COM component in Unix

Tags: windows, unix, com-interop

There is a COM component developed in windows machine. Can it be consumed in an application in Unix machine? I think it should be possible as COM is a binary standard.

Answer (score 0):

COM components are technologies supported only by Windows Desktop/Compact.
It is not supported by UWP or Unix.

Comment: Ok. But as per my knowledge Unix version of dotnet visual studio can be installed in Unix machine. So that way can we atleast create COM component in Unix machine.

Comment: Microsoft provides VisualStudio to any of Windows / Unix / Mac, and it also has a cross-compile function for each different OS.
Therefore, you can create COM components on Unix machines as well. However, because Unix / Mac does not have the necessary technology, the COM component will not work.
If the .NET core /. NET Standard specification will update in the future, it may support COM components, but it does not work now.

Comment: Ok. I agree you clarification. But have few queries: What could be the File format of the COM component created in Unix machine. In windows it is win 32 dll PE format. In Unix it should be COFF format ryt?  If yes, then where can we use this COFF format COM component? If it cannot be used in windows and Unix machine does not have the technology, then what purpose will it serve?

Comment: I do not know the details of the executable file format.
However, although COM technology is closely tied to the Windows registry database and ole32.dll at least, they should not exist on Unix / Mac.
If they are ported to Unix / Mac or alternative technologies are implemented, COM components will also work.

Comment: I came across below link about developing COM and DCOM on microsoft site. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260790.aspx .

Comment: The technology you introduced is mainly used as communication data representation of RPC, not COM as a program, and the same program will not work on both Windows and Unix.
These current attempts are .NET Core / .NET Standard and Windows Subsystem for Linux.
Even for the current UWP, the API of COM technology (IDispatch etc.) is prepared, but there should be restrictions such as being effective only on Windows for Desktop.
However, the world is moving in the direction of HTTP, HTML, REST, JavaScript, and Microsoft is also focusing on that.